# How to get list of all available keyboards on Windows Phone Mango (in C# code)?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How to get list of all available keyboards on Windows Phone Mango (in C# code)?
Or how to programmatically set custom keyboard for typing?
For example I want set the keyboard to Russian language for typing in my translator app to translate it into English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the keyboard language in code. That's up to the user. But with Mango, the user can have multiple keyboards, and switch with a single button press.

You should simply assume that the user will do this.

Comment: It's mean if the user forgets to change language form EN to RU, then he will type latin letters instead of russian letters?

Comment: Yes, and there's **nothing** you can do about it.

Comment: Nonsense. It's **very** good that evil programmers can't decide what keyboard the user wants to use.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen, I disagree... for instance, it would be very useful in a translation application (set the keyboard language to the source language automatically). It's not because some programmers are evil that everything should be forbidden to all programmers. Some people commit murder with knives, but knives are not forbidden...

Answer (score -2):

Here you will find a list of all available InputScopes -> http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2011/07/windows-phone-7-mango-tutorial-26-what.html

Comment: I think I need somethink else, not input scopes(btw, there is no somethink related to keyboard languages/layouts in your link). I am going to develope tranlator application based on Bing translator. For example if user chooses translation direction RU->EN (from Russian to English), then I need to set keyboard layout to Russian already when user taps to textbox for typing word for translation!